# JSTL <c:forEach items="${......" what are the type restrictions

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, hashset

I need to use a set to not allow duplicate values.

I need to list them out using the JSTL

```
<c:forEach items="${mySet}" var="set">
   //Code work done here
</c:forEach>
```

Usually I use the standard array or List here but what are the type restrictions if I want to use a HashSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [JSTL 1.1 mr2](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=52): `Collection`, `Map`, arrays, `Iterator` and `Enumeration`.

Answer (score 2):

Check this page: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0318/

Hashset implements java.util.Collection so it should work.